# Java Swing weird Gui output when creating a 10x10 grid of JPanels in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, variables, netbeans, jpanel

So I have been looking at this problem and debugging for days, and I cant find where is the problem. 
I am making a Battleship game, and I need to create 2 10x10 grids for player and opponent.
I was using NetBeans Designer tool to create this simple layout. 2 Labels, 3 Buttons, and 2 Panels which will act as a wrapper for my grids. 
(I set layout of those wrapper pannels to GridLayout with 10 columns and 10 rows)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kik5e.jpg

Then I made a simple code to populate those wrappers with grids.

```
public void initFields()
{

    pan = new JPanel[10][10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            pan[i][j] = new JPanel();
            pan[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pan[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            pan[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
            wrapper1.add(pan[i][j]);
        }
    }

    pan2 = new JPanel[10][10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            pan2[i][j] = new JPanel();
            pan2[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pan2[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            pan2[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
            wrapper2.add(pan[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And at the end I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysvya.jpg

My JPannel pan gets populated in wrapper2, and wrapper1 stays empty.
Tried debugging, making Gui Snapshot, and everything seems as it should be, but the end result is contrary to everything else.

Comment: Also here is my Navigator view that I got after making part of gui with Designer tool. http://i.imgur.com/zsywHBO.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second loop You are adding `pan[][]` again instead of `pan2[][]`:

```
wrapper2.add(pan2[i][j]);
                ^
```

Comment: Guess I've been programming for too long, I am starting not to see obvious stuff. I literally tried everything that I could think of, but I didn't see this beginners mistake.